# How to add a single map entry to priority queue

Tags: java, priority-queue

At the moment I have to add the whole map, as shown in the last line.

```
PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> sortedCells = new PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(3, new mem());
    Map<String,Integer> pn = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    pn.put("hello", 1);
    pn.put("bye", 3);
    pn.put("goodbye", 8);
    sortedCells.addAll(pn.entrySet());
```

What if I just wanted to add

```
("word" 5)
```

If i do

```
sortedCells.add("word",5)
```

I get an argument error.

How can I add a single element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add a `Map.Entry` object and not just `("word", 5)` **because the generic type of your priority queue is `Map.Entry<String, Integer>`**. In this case you should probably create your own `Map.Entry` class:

```
final class MyEntry implements Map.Entry<String, Integer> {
    private final String key;
    private Integer value;

    public MyEntry(String key, Integer value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer setValue(Integer value) {
        Integer old = this.value;
        this.value = value;
        return old;
    }
}
```

In your code you can now call:

```
sortedCells.add(new MyEntry("word",5));
```

If you don't want to implement your own entry you could use [AbstractMap.SimpleEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html):

```
sortedCells.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Integer>("word",5));
```

Comment: Although it does not pose a serious problem, if i print sortedcells it shows:[hello=1, bye=3, test.MyEntry@a32b, goodbye=8] , how can i get  test.MyEntry@a32b to appear as word=5? Also is it best to have the my entry class in a separate java file, or can it be in the same one?

Comment: I edited the question, you can use `SimpleEntry` instead of your own (I found it after writing the original question). `SimpleEntry` implements `toString()` and you will get the same result. Or just implement `toString()` in your `MyEntry`. If this is a use case that repeats itself and you would like to have your own structure I would use `MyEntry` (with a different descriptive name). If it's simple as you presented I would use `SimpleEntry`

Comment: yes, if a toString function is implemented in myEntry it does lead to the output needed