# Find the values corresponding to k-large elements

Tags: java, external-sorting

My question is regarding data from a large file.

I have a huge file which is in this format - Primary_key Value(
Eg: 10000001 1
    10000002 5
    10000009 200 etc.
I want to find the values corresponding to the k - large elements in the primary_key column. For ex: If k=2, it should output 200 and 5 as per above example.

As it is a very large file, I was planning on using min heap method and I understand that pretty well. However, my data is in a key-value pair and I don't know how I can use that in the min heap sorting.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this. Greatly appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

yes your approach is right, you can use priority queue(with min heap) to achieve this. you can store your data in a map, then use it in priority queue like below.

```
PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> a.getValue()-b.getValue());
//psuedo code
for (line in file)
{ 
    //line[0] - denotes key and line[1] - denotes value
    count = map.getOrDefault(line[0], 0);
    map.put(num, count+line[1]);
}
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : counterMap.entrySet()) {
    pq.offer(entry);
    if(pq.size() > k) 
     pq.poll();
}

List<Integer> res = new LinkedList<>();
while(!pq.isEmpty()) {
    res.add(0, pq.poll().getValue());
}
return res;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. However I am still kind of stuck. So I thought I will check my algorithm with you and proceed

Comment: Step 1. Read the lines from the file one by one.
Step 2: Create a min heap of the size k(as you are finding k large elements)
   while(br.ready() && (s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Integer j = Integer.parseInt(s);
    System.out.println(j+"/n");
      for(int i=0; i<=HeapDemo.HEAP_SIZE;i++){
             minHeap.add(j);
Step 3: Compare and add/remove the first element

Comment: I have added complete pseudo code in my answer, and I made an assumption that your key might have multiple entries in the file and will have to sum the entries based on same key. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks again.I am adding elements to the priority queue as
minHeap.add(instructors.entrySet()); However I get the error : The method add(Map.Entry<String,Integer>) in the type PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> is not applicable for the arguments (Set<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>). Could you help?

Comment: can you try  minHeap.addAll(instructors.entrySet()) if that doesn't work check this answer in this link?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045451/how-to-add-a-single-map-entry-to-priority-queue
let me know if this works!

Comment: Thank you for the pseudo code. I have used remove command instead of poll.

But mainly, you have written 
if(pq.size() > k) 
pq.poll(); 

That is remove the head nodeif the size of  the heap is greater than k. However what I want to accomplish is - I only want to remove the node element if the "key" from file is smaller than the "key" in the priority queue. How can I achieve this? I see element() method for priority queue but it returns the entire element(key+value) not just the "key". Also at the end, using the iterator, I only want to display the "value" from the minheap.

Comment: cool! I am not sure why you want to check on the "key" before removing? it should be the value right? but glad you got it working. upvote my answer if it had helped you.

Comment: I see that the time complexity of this algorithm is O(N log K). Is that right? I am unable to find the memory complexity though. Do you have any suggestion